Find none overlapping intervals using sqlite
I have a data base with ids and time intervals example:



TimeId
Start
End




1
0
10


1
2
13


1
11
21


1
15
30


2
0
10


2
2
13


2
11
21


2
15
30



I want to write a query which selects none-overlapping intervals.Rows with different TimeId are considered non-overlapping even if the range [start, end] from both overlaps. So expected output from the previous example would be



TimeId
Start
End




1
0
10


1
11
21


2
0
10


2
11
21



another possible output



timeid
start
end




1
0
10


1
15
30


2
0
10


2
15
30



or



timeid
start
end




1
2
13


1
15
30


2
0
10


2
15
30



or



timeid
start
end




1
2
13


1
15
30


2
2
13


2
15
30



What is important is that you output as much as possible none-overlapping intervals.
So Basically there are two conditions:

The output must not contain overlaping intervals (where the defintion of overlaping contains also the timeid as explained above)
In the remaining (not selected or filtered out) rows there must be no rows which can be added to the result without breaking the first condition. Meaning: if I added any other row from the not selected ones, the outputed result will contain now an overlapping interval. Maybe I can rephrase this condition as the outputted set of rows should be maximum.

So for example the following output is not acceptable:



timeid
start
end




1
2
13


1
15
30


2
2
13



sine I can add the row



timeid
start
end




2
15
30



and it will still not overlaps with any of the three outputted rows.
Example database
CREATE TABLE "test" (
    "timeid" INTEGER,
    "start"  INTEGER,
    "end"    INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES(1, 0, 10);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1, 2, 13);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1, 3, 15);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1, 11, 21);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1, 15, 30);

INSERT INTO test VALUES(2, 0, 10);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2, 2, 13);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2, 11, 21);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2, 15, 30);

Last thing which gave hope was
with recursive nol(id, start, end) AS (
  select test.timeid, test.start, test.end from test inner join 
 ( select timeid as ttid, min(start) as ttstart from test group by id)  as tt on
 tt.ttid = test.timeid and tt.ttstart = test.start
    union all 
    select test.timeid , test.start, test.end from test  inner join nol 
    on test.timeid = nol.id and test.start > nol.end    
    GROUP By test.timeid
    Having min(test.start)
)
select * from nol 

Assumptions and Problems
In the above code (and in the real case that I have), as you may noticed, i assume that the combination timeid and start are unique, i.e., no two rows shoud have the same timeid and start.
The problem with the above code is that it is not supported. I get the error (Result: recursive aggregate queries not supported).
Could you please help what would be an alternative to using aggregate inside recursive?
thanks in advance

In fact, all intervals in your data have at least one other overlapping interval. It’s kind of unclear to me by what logic you wish to arrive at your desired result? Is this about consecutive intervals?

why should the output not be (1,2,13),(1,15,30),(2,2,13),(2,15,30) ? Or (1,0,10),(1,15,30),((2,0,10),(2,15,30) ?

Thanks for taking the time for my question. I can see the confusion. I will update the question. However, I will tell the logic quickly here. The order of the intervals is not important what is important that I output the maximum possible set of none-overlapping intervals. So you can start with any interval. Then when you add another one to it it should not overlaps with it then you try to add a third one and so on till you cannot add any more rows.

consider (1,1,2),(1,3,4),(1,5,6),(1,1,10000). Determining that (1,1,10000) is better than (1,1,2),(1,3,4),(1,5,6) isn't completely trivial

You could try to prepare your data in a way that you can recognize the possible overlaps, flag them and filter the result accordingly.
With your sample data the code resulting as in one of your expectations is:
--      prepare your table data for overlap testings 
WITH 
  grid AS
    ( Select      t.timeid, t.starts, t.ends, 
                  ( Select Max(starts) From tbl Where timeid = t.timeid And starts < t.starts ) as last_start, 
                  ( Select Max(ends) From tbl Where timeid = t.timeid And starts < t.starts ) as last_end, 
                  t2.starts as starts_2, t2.ends as ends_2 
      From        tbl t
      Left Join   tbl t2 ON( t2.timeid = t.timeid And 
                             t2.starts > t.ends ) 
    ), 
--      overlaps and flags - final preparation for main SQL  
  overlaps AS 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT
                 g.timeid, g.starts, g.ends, 
                 g2.starts as starts_overlap, g2.ends as ends_overlap,
                 Case When g2.starts < LAG(g2.ends) Over(Partition By g2.timeid Order By g2.starts)
                      Then 'OUT' 
                 Else 'IN' 
                 End as flag
      FROM       tbl t
      INNER JOIN ( Select     * 
                   From       grid
                   Where      last_start Is Null OR starts > last_end
                 ) g ON( ( g.timeid = t.timeid  And g.starts = t.starts And g.ends = t.ends )  
                        OR
                         ( g.timeid = t.timeid  And g.starts_2 = t.starts And g.ends_2 = t.ends )  
                       )
      LEFT JOIN  grid g2 ON( g2.timeid = t.timeid And g2.starts > t.starts And g2.starts < t.ends )
      ORDER BY   t.timeid, t.starts
    ) 

--      S Q L : 
Select     t.* 
From       overlaps o 
Inner Join tbl t ON( t.timeid = o.timeid And 
                          t.starts = Coalesce(o.starts_overlap, o.starts) And 
                          t.ends = Coalesce(o.ends_overlap, o.ends) )
Where      ( o.starts_overlap Is Null OR o.starts_overlap > o.ends ) And o.flag = 'IN'
Order By   o.timeid, o.starts 

R e s u l t :



timeid
starts
ends




1
0
10


1
15
30


2
0
10


2
15
30



fiddle
